# How to optimize regexp_replace performance for multiple substrings in PostgreSQL

Tags: regex, postgresql, performance

I need to remove multiple substrings from a column of strings. I have  ~200k rows, as well as a large bag of custom "stopwords."

Specifically, I have a table (NameTable), with a `Names` column full of multiple-word strings. Only a small subset of the words in each string is relevant for what I'm doing next. `names` has a `trigram/GIN` index. Is there any way to speed up a query like the following, but with a much larger string of target words? I'm using PG10.

...

```
Create Index Names_trgm on NameTable using gin(Name gin_trgm_ops);

Update NameTable
   set CleanedName = regexp_replace(Name, '( fuzzy| wuzzy| was| a | bear | the |
first| time | yossarian| saw | the | chaplain | he | fell| madly| in | love|
with| him)',' ','g');
```

Comment: First of all do not update whole table, filter it: `update ... where Name ~ '( fuzzy| wuzzy| was| a | bear | the |
first| time | yossarian| saw | the | chaplain | he | fell| madly| in | love|
with| him)';`

Comment: Great, that allows the query to take advantage of the index. Performance = improved.